# Using the legacy Dev Mode with GWT 2.8.2 and Java 1.8?

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, smartgwt-pro

We have been using this software combination

- Java 1.7
- GWT 2.6.0
- SmartGWT 6.0p-20170922

But we want to upgrade to Java 1.8, so we set out to try this combination

- Java 1.8
- GWT 2.8.2
- SmartGWT 6.1p-20180216

I was expecting that the new environment would force me to use SuperDevMode.  But to my surprise, it actually allows me to still use the legacy "DevMode" (that is, debug code in JVM/Eclipse rather than in Browser).  I also had trouble setting up SuperDevMode anyway.

So here is my question:  are there any people out there who are using GWT 2.8.x but still using the legacy "DevMode".  What is your experience with it?  Thanks!

Eventually if we can get SuperDevMode to work, we are happy to try it.  But having the option to use DevMode would be a big plus for me to convince my team mates to upgrade.  People can then migrate to use SuperDevMode at their own pace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what the question is.

But yes, while Super Dev Mode is the new Dev Mode, the old Legacy Dev Mode continues to be supported, and the plan is that it will not go away in GWT 2.x.

However, new features may not work in it - the core contributors are not planning on adding support for any features added in GWT 2.8 and beyond. For example, while Java 8 language support appears to work, some Java 8 APIs are not likely to behave correctly. Additionally, JsInterop, the replacement for JSNI and JSOs does not work, which means Elemental2 will not work, which will limit the ability to adopt new libraries and frameworks.

If all you need to do is to support a legacy codebase that doesn't plan on adding support for new tools and features, legacy dev mode is available to encourage continuing to upgrade (which will still get you bugfixes and other incremental improvements in the toolkit itself). But when the time comes for new features in your project, you'll have the make the switch to Super Dev Mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is exactly what I need to know!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can look into the Eclipse plugin from branflake to get SuperDevMode to work.

Working with SuperDevMode for me was a big step up from DevMode. Especially because of the performance gains and fast recompiles.

https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin

Look at the YouTube video's to see how to set it up.